# Two buttons in one line

Tags: php, html

How can I  put this buttons in one line?

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="render_button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render </button>

    <button type="submit" name="check" class='btn btn-block btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render2 </button>
</form>
```

Comment: From the code you have given, they are both on the same line.

Comment: This is in Bootstrap, correct?

Comment: ^ bootstrap has `.form-inline` doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this uses Bootstrap, which I'm guessing by the btn btn-primary tags, just add **display: inline-block;** to each style tag:

**NOTE:** You may have to 0 out the margin-top on the second button, I'll add that as well.

```
<form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="render_button" class='btn btn-block btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;display:inline-block;" > Render </button>

        <button type="submit" name="check" class='btn btn-block btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;display:inline-block;margin-top:0;" > Render2 </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `btn-block` class is your culprit, if you remove it the buttons should display as in-line elements

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="render_button" class='btn btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render </button>

    <button type="submit" name="check" class='btn btn-primary' style="width:100px;height:30px;" > Render2 </button>
</form>
```